# Apps Script Trying to set a variable based on edit value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation, triggers

I have a macro set up to send an email to a general mailbox that I would like to add the ability to specify the recipient of the email (being the email of the estimator named in the dropdown box). The estimator is chosen from a dropdown data validation box that is on a different page.

Google Apps Script does not have the ability to run multiple installable triggers of the same kind of trigger on the same sheet (i.e. you cannot run more than 1 OnEdit installable trigger on the same project). If it could handle multiple installable OnEdit triggers, I would just run each individual instance of the MailApp.sendEmail trigger on different functions with the correct information in each one. The spreadsheet is referenced correctly and rData has taken into consideration the array format.

I have very little experience so I am spinning in circles trying to fix this issue. This is what I have come to by now.
(personal information has been replaced with @example.com)

```
function sendEmail(e){


const rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,11).getValues();
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();   
const opportunity = rData [0][0];
const estimator =  rData [0][4];
const projectName = rData [0][1];
const date = rData [0][5];
const now = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US");
const msg = 'Hello, this is to notify you of the recent project assigned on ' + now;
const subject =  opportunity + ' ' + projectName + ' has been assigned to ' + estimator + ', due on '+ date;
const body = msg;
const options = { cc: "logan@example.com"}


  if (e.range.columnStart != 5 || e.value != "Matt") return;

    let recipient = "matt@example.com";



 Logger.log(recipient, subject, msg);

MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)
}
```

This works for one recipient, I have not been able to add anyone past the first. I have a total of 11 estimators that I want to specify, but I have no idea if this is even possible or if google will only allow me to send the info to a single estimator.

I have tried putting the estimators in an array, adding them individually, running else if statements, creating a line for each individual, redefining recipient, using GmailApp.sendEmail, everything I can think of to make this work. Having only the experience gained through hours of googling, I an not sure what the limitations are of Apps Script.

Results when I have attempted to define multiple emails, I get Syntax error: SyntaxError: Identifier 'recipient' has already been declared line: 21 file: SendEmail.gs

```html
function sendEmail(e){


const rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,11).getValues();
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();   
const opportunity = rData [0][0];
const estimator =  rData [0][4];
const projectName = rData [0][1];
const date = rData [0][5];
const now = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US");
const msg = 'Hello, this is to notify you of the recent project assigned on ' + now;
const subject =  opportunity + ' ' + projectName + ' has been assigned to ' + estimator + ', due on '+ date;
const body = msg;
const options = { cc: "logan@example.com"}


  if (e.range.columnStart != 5 || e.value != "Matt") return;
    let recipient = "matt@example.com";
    
  if (e.range.columnStart != 5 || e.value != "Rob") return;
    let recipient = 'rob@example.com';


 Logger.log(recipient, subject, msg);

MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)
}
```

When attempting to modify the return value with the desired email address, no email was sent.

```html
function sendEmail(e){


const rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,11).getValues();
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();   
const opportunity = rData [0][0];
const estimator =  rData [0][4];
const projectName = rData [0][1];
const date = rData [0][5];
const now = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US");
const msg = 'Hello, this is to notify you of the recent project assigned on ' + now;
const subject =  opportunity + ' ' + projectName + ' has been assigned to ' + estimator + ', due on '+ date;
const body = msg;
const options = { cc: "logan@example.com"}


  if (e.range.columnStart != 5 || e.value != "Matt") return (recipient = "matt@example.com");

  if (e.range.columnStart != 5 || e.value != "Rob") return (recipient = "rob@example.com");


 Logger.log(recipient, subject, msg);

MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)
}
```

When removing the return statement and directly linking the email to the edit, an email was sent to Rob if the edit value is Matt or Rob, without differentiating between the two (where I referenced above it only sends the email to the last listed recipient.)

```html
function sendEmail(e){


const rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,11).getValues();
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();   
const opportunity = rData [0][0];
const estimator =  rData [0][4];
const projectName = rData [0][1];
const date = rData [0][5];
const now = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US");
const msg = 'Hello, this is to notify you of the recent project assigned on ' + now;
const subject =  opportunity + ' ' + projectName + ' has been assigned to ' + estimator + ', due on '+ date;
const body = msg;
const options = { cc: "logan@example.com"}


  if (e.range.columnStart != 5 || e.value != "Matt"); recipient = "matt@example.com";

  if (e.range.columnStart != 5 || e.value != "Rob") ; recipient = 'rob@example.com';


 Logger.log(recipient, subject, msg);

MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)
}
```

When changing the if statement to an else if statement, Syntax error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'else' line: 19 file: SendEmail.gs

```html
function sendEmail(e){


const rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,11).getValues();
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();   
const opportunity = rData [0][0];
const estimator =  rData [0][4];
const projectName = rData [0][1];
const date = rData [0][5];
const now = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US");
const msg = 'Hello, this is to notify you of the recent project assigned on ' + now;
const subject =  opportunity + ' ' + projectName + ' has been assigned to ' + estimator + ', due on '+ date;
const body = msg;
const options = { cc: "logan@example.com"}


  if (e.range.columnStart != 5 || e.value != "Matt"); recipient = "matt@example.com";

  else if (e.range.columnStart != 5 || e.value != "Rob"); recipient = 'rob@example.com';


 Logger.log(recipient, subject, msg);

MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)
}
```

I am trying to update this thread with information as I try things and get suggestions, please forgive my inexperience on questions like this. I feel like I am throwing paint at a wall and seeing what sticks.

Comment: Will you be using only one estimator at a time?

Comment: @Cooper I'm not sure exactly what you are asking for, but there is only ever 1 estimator assigned to a project at a time. They are selected from a data validation drop box listed on a different sheet. They will all have access to the spreadsheet as a reference, more than anything, but I need to be able to have the option to change that person as needed.

Comment: How do you assign an estimator to a project?

Comment: @BlindSpots the estimator that is selected in the drop down box is the recipient of the email. The error that is thrown comes as recipient is already defined, even though it is inputed as a variable. The issue I am running into is when the variable is being treated as a constant. When recipient is already defined, it defaults to the last listed email and it doesn't check the rest of the code, it just sees that an edit was made and uses the last listed. "SyntaxError: recipient already defined" appears when I copy the if statement and change the recipient email address and edit name.

Comment: Running the statements as else if for each of the different inputs sends the email to the last listed email, regardless of the edit input. It seems as if the edit alone will trigger the email to be sent  without running through the entire if statements. I tried running a return statement where if (e.range.columnStart != 5 || e.value != "Matt") return (result = matt@example.com); SyntaxError result is undefined.

Comment: @Cooper the project is assigned by selecting an option from a data validation box.

Comment: Is the parameter for you function populated by the onFormSubmission trigger for a spreadsheet?

Comment: Please tell me a little more about the validation box.  I hardly ever use Google Forms.  I prefer to roll my own.

Comment: @Cooper it is all manually entered. It is set up the same way you would on excel, where your options are stored on a different page and you can select the estimator from a drop down box. I actually don't use Google Forms and have no clue how that feature works. I set the installable trigger to run sendEmail(e) onEdit, so it triggers any time information is added or changed in the spreadsheet

Comment: So does e.values[4] represent the estimator name?  That would be column5 in the linked sheet.  If you are not familiar with that event object it's explained [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)

Comment: @Cooper yes, the rData is in correct array form. Column 5 is where the Estimator Name data validation is located.

Comment: Then what is `opportunity`?  In all of the forms I've used column one is a timestamp

Comment: The information in the Opportunity column is the auto generated reference number for each project. It runs in a separate line from the project name in column 2, project address in column 3, project owner in 4, estimator in 5, due date in 6, due time in 7.

Comment: Copy [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74522170/1330560). I won't tell your teacher.

Comment: @BlindSpots hopefully this helps. I believe I have captured the information so far so you don't have to reference the comments to see what has happened since you last looked at the question.

Comment: your ``recipient`` var is not part of the ``if`` statements.  Format should be: ``if (condition) { 'code block' }`` see JavaScript [if, else, and else if](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp) you used a one line shortcut (no curly braces) for multi-line statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @BlindSpots for helping me recognize the simple error of curly brackets.

"your recipient var is not part of the if statements. Format should be: if (condition) { 'code block' } see JavaScript if, else, and else if you used a one line shortcut (no curly braces) for multi-line statement."

Corrected,

```html
function sendEmail(e){


const rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,11).getValues();
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();   
const opportunity = rData [0][0];
const estimator =  rData [0][4];
const projectName = rData [0][1];
const date = rData [0][5];
const now = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US");
const msg = 'Hello, this is to notify you of the recent project assigned on ' + now;
const subject =  opportunity + ' ' + projectName + ' has been assigned to ' + estimator + ', due on '+ date;
const body = msg;
const options = { cc: "logan@example.com"}


  if (e.range.columnStart != 5 || e.value != "Matt") {recipient = "matt@example.com"};

  if (e.range.columnStart != 5 || e.value != "Rob") {recipient = 'rob@example.com'};


 Logger.log(recipient, subject, msg);

MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)
}
```

I cannot believe it is that simple, but the answers consistently are.